# ¿Se usa de forma metafórica la expresión "el día de la marmota" en Hispanoamérica?

Tags: expresiones, diferencias-regionales, hispanoamérica

Hace poco oí a un reportero de RTVE (el principal medio de comunicación estatal español) usar la expresión "el día de la marmota" de forma figurada:

> Aquí estamos con la sensación del día de la marmota, de *déjà vu*...

Estaba cubriendo la noticia de la reapertura de los bares y restaurantes en Baleares, si no recuerdo mal, tras haber bajado los casos de Covid-19. En España se usa mucho la expresión con el sentido de estar viviendo la misma situación una y otra vez. De hecho, en el [CORPES XXI](https://webfrl.rae.es/CORPES/view/inicioExterno.view) se encuentran ya algunos casos:

> *Me preocupaba que fuera un parto en posterior, de nuevo. Me preocupaba que tuviera frenillo, de nuevo, que tuviera reflujo, de nuevo, que tuviéramos otra lactancia horrible, de nuevo. Me preocupaba sentir el día de la marmota.*
>
> Beatriz M. Muñoz, «El embarazo cuando ya tienes hijos», 2016-03-16.

> *El día de la Marmota tuvo su última entrega ayer, cuando una vez más, la «premier» anunció que cruzaría el Canal de la Mancha para pedir una revisión del acuerdo de retirada.*
>
> «May logra el aval para renegociar con la UE». La Razón. 2019-01-29.

> *Un nuevo capítulo del día de la marmota, en el que todos los expertos electorales coinciden en su escasa rentabilidad en las urnas, pero sea por inercia o por respeto a las tradiciones se mantienen.*
>
> Ramón Gorriarán, «El panorama nacional. Cita con las urnas a la sombra del 15M». Diario de León, 2011-05-22.

> *Y, claro, de repente volvemos a tener fecha para un posible fin del mundo. Esta semana hemos vuelto a hablar también de planetas extrasolares, de neutrinos y la velocidad de la luz... Parece que marzo comienza como un día de la marmota eterno.*
>
> Javier Armentia, «Un impacto cósmico para 2040 (y otras noticias recurrentes)». Cosmos, 2012-03-01.

Aparte de que le acabo de preguntar a la RAE en Twitter si planean ya la inclusión de esta expresión en el diccionario, dado que la expresión tiene al menos una década de uso generalizado, me he dado cuenta de que absolutamente todos los ejemplos que he encontrado y citado del CORPES XXI son de España. Lo cual me hace preguntarme: ¿es esta expresión usada con este sentido también en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: En España entiendo yo que se hizo famoso el concepto a partir de la película [_Groundhog Day_](https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film245798.html), de 1993, que aquí se tradujo como _Atrapado en el tiempo_. Veo [en la wiki](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day) que en Chile, Argentina, México y Venezuela se tradujo exactamente como _El día de la marmota_, por lo que no me extrañaría que la referencia cinematográfica haya permeado en el habla coloquial.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' por supuesto, justo va y se me olvida especificar eso en la pregunta. Efectivamente, se hizo popular a partir de esa película. Se me ocurre que igual podríamos preguntar qué títulos de películas han llegado a convertirse en palabras o expresiones de pleno derecho del español (reconocidas en el DLE).

Comment: ¡Suena muy bien! Seguro que encontraríamos una infinidad

Answer (score 4):

Puedo decir que fuera de España la expresión es también usada —como consecuencia de la popularidad y difusión de la película "Groundhog Day" de Bill Murray. Tal como se puede leer en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day), la misma se distribuyó e hizo conocida en toda Hispanoamérica. (E incluso fue titulada de forma literal como "El día de la marmota" en Chile, Argentina, México  y Venezuela)

> Groundhog Day (Atrapado en el tiempo en España, El día de la marmota en Chile, Argentina, México y Venezuela y Hechizo del tiempo en el resto de Hispanoamérica) es una película de Cine fantástico y alto contenido metafísico estadounidense de 1993 dirigida por Harold Ramis, y protagonizada por Bill Murray, Andie MacDowell, y Chris Elliott

En la cultura argentina se ven ejemplos diarios de uso:

- este artículo (https://www.lanacion.com.ar/opinion/el-dia-marmota-cristina-kirchner-nid2538034/) de uno de los principales diarios de tirada nacional, haciendo uso de la expresión para hablar del re-tratamiento legislativo de la ley del Aborto, recientemente aprobada en el país. En uno de sus párrafo puede leerse la metáfora en contexto

> *La legalización del aborto ***vuelve como el Día de la Marmota*** a la vida política de Cristina Fernández, primero como presidenta, después como Senadora y ahora como vicepresidenta*

- esta [otra nota de un medio del sur argentino](https://www.rionegro.com.ar/estropeen-los-rosales-con-cartelitos-mataron-a-una-chica-en-villa-la-angostura-1703495/) sobre un feminicidio

> *En 2018 tras el doble femicidio de Las Ovejas el gobernador Gutiérrez anunció en su discurso de apertura de sesiones, que enviaría un proyecto para crear el cuerpo de abogadas y abogados que patrocinen a las víctimas de violencia por razones de género. Se convirtió en ley rápidamente pero se reglamentó hace dos meses y no hay equipo. Las dos profesionales que prestan servicios dependen de Nación y no reciben casos del interior de la provincia.*
>
> *El mandatario promete que el lunes en su discurso habrá anuncios. Es **como el Día de la Marmota**, nada cambia, apenas detalles.*